# dotnet core entity framework connection closed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to create an API backed by mssql and entity framework.

Everything seems to go well until I start to hook up the frontend.

I am getting exceptions saying `System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.` or `System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is closed.` depending on which API finishes first.

Here is chromes view
[image: chrome]

I have the following in my startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(opt => {
    opt.UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(Configuration["CONNECTIONSTRINGS_AZURECONNECTION"]), builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("Application.Web"));
    opt.UseOpenIddict();
});

services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

All of my repositories are scoped

```
services.AddScoped<INotificationRepository, NotificationRepository>();
```

And so is the database context

```
services.AddScoped<ApplicationContext, ApplicationContext>();
```

Both controllers are basically the same

```
private readonly INotificationRepository _notificationRepository;

public NotificationsController(UserManager<User> userManager, INotificationRepository notificationRepository)
    :base(userManager)
{
    _notificationRepository = notificationRepository;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
{
    var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
    return new OkObjectResult(await _notificationRepository.FindByAsync(n => n.User == user));
}
```

Am I correct in thinking that the context needs to be scoped per request?
And each chrome call is a separate request which would create a separate scope?

So each call would basically be:

1. Request
2. Auth filters
3. Controller
4. async function
5. async get current user -> return user (dont destroy context)
6. async repository function
7. return from repository
8. return from controller

Google is no help so I assume I am doing something incorrectly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was this line:

```
opt.UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(Configuration["CONNECTIONSTRINGS_AZURECONNECTION"]), builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("Application.Web"));
```

Once I changed it to this everything works as expected

```
opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration["CONNECTIONSTRINGS_AZURECONNECTION"], builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("Application.Web"));
```

Comment: Passing SqlConnection haven't solved my case, but helped me to have more details to solve the problem. Solved using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543595/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-a-common-cause-of-this-error-is-disposing-a-con