# Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have written a simple application and when I navigate to my edit page the below error pops up.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]

> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'app.Models.ApplicationDbContext'.

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

It seems EF is providing a useful information which I can not understand. The tricky part of this error is that it happens randomly when I navigate to the edit page. Sometime it works, Sometimes it fails to load some properties on `Edit.cshtml` but still works and sometimes the application crashes with provided error just in my console. Another strange happen is that it dose not generate any `500` or `5xx` error. It just simply crashes and stop the application.

Here is my `Edit.cshtml` content:

```
@page
@model EditModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Book";
}

<h2>Edit Book</h2>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form method="post" class="form-border">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="validation-container alert alert-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span class="form-text text-danger" asp-validation-for="Book.Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Description"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Description" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Book.Author"></label>
                <input asp-for="Book.Author" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <input asp-for="Book.Id" type="hidden">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
            <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success">Back To List</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is My `Edit.cshtm.cs` `OnGet` method:

```
public async void OnGet(int id)
{
    Book = await _db.Books.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    if(Book == null)
    {
        RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

I am using `.Net Core 2.2.104`

Also when I run command `dotnet ef --version` it generates `Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 2.2.2-servicing-10034`

Comment: read this [article](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/12/22/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext/)

Answer (score 177, accepted):

This is because of your method return type `async void`. In general, when you are using `async void` in your code it’s bad news, because:

- You can’t wait for its completion
- Any unhandled exceptions will terminate your process (ouch!)

So return `async Task` instead of `async void` from your method as follows:

```
public async Task OnGet(int id)
{
    Book = await _db.Books.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    if(Book == null)
    {
       RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

For more details:

- [C# – beware of async void in your code](https://theburningmonk.com/2012/10/c-beware-of-async-void-in-your-code/)
- [Cannot access a disposed object in ASP.NET Core when injecting DbContext](https://thinkrethink.net/2017/12/22/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-in-asp-net-core-when-injecting-dbcontext/)

Comment: I'm having this problem too, but nowhere do I use async void, always use async Task

Comment: @brando Then the problem lies in anywhere in your code. Please ask a separate question with your code. Hope I or someone else will help you.

Comment: I discovered my error.  Very frustrating until you realize the simple fix

Comment: Thank you so much. I was tearing my hair out and was beginning to think that Azure's Free Tier sucks big time when in reality, the problem again sat in front of the PC.

Comment: Thanks in advance, but how I can call "public async Task OnGet()" method from a Thread calling??

Comment: @SelimReza `await OnGet()`

Comment: @TanvirArjel , you have shown normal calling process, but I want to know the process by Thread calling.

Comment: @SelimReza Please a look here: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Hit this problem today.  And it's nice to know why it happened as well.

Comment: @TanvirArjel - you're a legend. First SO search result and your post was an immediate fix! Good man. Async Void - bad dog! Get in your bed!

Answer (score 63):

**UPDATED ANSWER WHEN THE PROBLEM IS NOT A TASK OF TYPE VOID**
The accepted answer is fine if you are using a voided method. There is another potential problem with a simple solution if your method is not a void.

1. Did you implement a pattern or some type of separation of concerns? Controller => Service => Repository

Verify that your controller method is async Task if the methods down the line are also async Task. In my case the problem was the fact that I did not put async on the controller method, but the downline methods were async Task.

Cheers!

Comment: I had the same issue, thanks a lot for this. I did a global search and found a couple more async void that I replaced with async Task to avoid potential future issues.

Comment: I literally dug up all my services functions and Repo as well. My Controller was not async. Adding it helped me.... Thanks man!

I was getting an "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed context instance. ..... " upon Calling savechanges method from Repo.

Comment: I was just returning IActionResult in my controller and had async methods down the line. I changed the return type to Task<IActionResult> and all is good now. Thanks, I would never have gotten that!

Comment: Thanks a lot! In my case I forgot an "await" somewhere in a function down the line.. as I was refactoring I forgot about that. This took me longer than expected.

Answer (score 45):

What I am about to post is NOT the answer to this particular question.  But it is related so just to save somebody headache I am posting it.  I was encountering this same error

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. etc

The following was the code with the bug (can you see it?):

```js
[HttpGet("processs/oxxo-spei/ticket-email/{paymentIdx}")]
public StatusCodeResult ProcessOxxoSpeiTicketEmailAsync(string paymentIdx)
{
    var paymentId = paymentIdx.DecodeRef();
            
    var response = _orderEngine.ProcessOxxoSpeiTicketEmailAsync(paymentId);

    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

The following change fixed it:

```js
[HttpGet("processs/oxxo-spei/ticket-email/{paymentIdx}")]
public async Task<StatusCodeResult> ProcessOxxoSpeiTicketEmailAsync(string paymentIdx)
{
    var paymentId = paymentIdx.DecodeRef();
            
    var response = await _orderEngine.ProcessOxxoSpeiTicketEmailAsync(paymentId);
                // ^^^^I HAD FORGOTTEN TO PUT AWAIT
    return StatusCode(200);
}
```

Yes that's right I had forgotten to put "await" before a function that used an EF Core dbcontext.  Adding 'await' fixed it.  So easy to miss it, especially if you're tired and under deadline.

Comment: Thanks dude, I had a controller hitting a non async method and then changed the service method it was hitting to async and never added aysnc method or await on the controller side, duhhh........

Comment: I was also not using async in my controller method and I feel like a complete moron, wrestled with this for two days.  Sometimes you just need to get up and take a walk.  Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Just to add, in short returning a Task will fix the issue and make sure object instance is not disposed

Comment: Wouldn't this be picked up in literally any editor...?

Comment: @fullStackChris I think now it is

Comment: I'm running into this problem today, with DbContext, I think it has much more to do with how classes are injected and when.

Comment: That was exactly it and in the exact circumstance that you suggested. Client testing tomorrow and I added in an async method in a controller that I did not place await in front of. Thanks, luckily I got here quickly and did not waste too much time on it.

Comment: Answer 8 and your answer are connected with each other need to make it async. The issue will fix. Thank you all.

Comment: Thanks, missed async in my controller method. Was staring for ages and just didnt see it. No error, just no data.

Answer (score 7):

### Alternative Solution to `async Task` conversions

---

You've tried...

- Making all methods in the callstack `async Task` instead of `async void`

After a *careful look* at my call stack, I had overridden the `SaveChangeAsync` method in my `DbContext`, and made a call to change the behavior of how `async` operates by default. This which resulted in my context being disposed and still trying to access it.

---

##### *Some code omitted for brevity*

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
  int result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

  // ignore events if no dispatcher provided
  if (dispatcher is null) return result;

  // dispatch events only if save was successful
  await DispatchEventsIfSaveSuccessful();
  return result;
}

private async Task DispatchEventsIfSaveSuccessful()
{
    var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker
        .Entries<Entity>()
        .Select(e => e.Entity)
        .Where(e => e.Events.Any())
        .ToArray();
...
    foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
    {
        var events = entity.Events.ToArray();
        entity.Events.Clear();
        foreach (var domainEvent in events)
        {
            await dispatcher.Dispatch(domainEvent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Problem way

`await dispatcher.Dispatch(domainEvent).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);`

#### The solution

omit the `ConfigureAwait(false)`

`await dispatcher.Dispatch(domainEvent);`

#### Explanation

ASP.NET Core does not use a [`SynchronizationContext`].(https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/).

When using `ConfigureAwait(false)` *options* on an `async` `Task`, the executing task will not resume on this context, but instead on a thread pool thread. Essentially by configuring that `await` call, when the [thread finished dispatching the events](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), the context was **already** disposed.

#### Advice

*Continue* looking through *each method/function* invocation from the *beginning of your request* all the way to when it **fails** and see if you may be altering the default behavior of `async/await` via `ConfigureAwait(false)` or a similar altering change.

For more information, I highly recommend [following this link](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) by Stephen Cleary on his blog about `async` more.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of problem this created? The fact that the continuation is resuming on a thread pool thread shouldn't allow the context to be disposed before it finishes (unless you're not awaiting your top-level SaveChangesAsync() call before disposing the context, in which case it would be functionally equivalent to async void).I feel like there must be more to the story than is reflected in your code snippets, like use of [ThreadStatic] fields or Task.Run() or something.

Comment: @JeremyTodd If I recall correctly, in the *entire* request pipeline that I used to construct this answer, there was no `ThreadStatic` or `Task.Runs`, etc. or anything other than standard `await/async`.

For reasons I've tried to understand from the documentation I linked in my answer, it appears an `async` call to the `SaveChangesAsync` that has a `ConfigureAwait` async call to the dispatcher caused this issue because it was the only change made that caused the error to completely disappear. It happened consistently on debug/release mode.

Comment: Kudos to you! Thanks for brief description

Answer (score 3):

Here is what actually worked for me in a situation where I was getting the same error as above when trying to access the data in Startup.cs to run some startup data building functions on server load, rather than a specific Controller action:

```
        IServiceScope scope = provider.CreateScope();
        YourDbContext context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
```

In the Configure method of Startup.cs, with IServiceProvider included as a parameter:

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider provider)
```

Just including that for anyone who wants to do the same in Startup.cs.

Comment: Thank you a lote, You solved my problem, That was a perfect solution, I had problem using **db** in **SignalR hubConnection**

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have resolved the issue taking guidance from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task
I made a scoped service and used method inside in that service as queued task.

Answer (score 1):

I found something else that causes this error, just posting it here for posterity.

I had cached the result of a query into memory as an `IQueryable`.

When pulling it out of the cache and calling `ToList()`, it worked successfully the first time. On page refresh however, it caused this error.

The solution is to not cache `IQueryable`, but do `ToList()` first.

Answer (score 0):

This is another anwser for who gonna read this topic.

I tried to trigger asnyc method with javascript. Because of that it can't triggered and so result didn't calculated by async method. I was returning json object to view like this in dotnet core mvc.

```
return Json(_service.AsyncMethod(parameter));
```

My IActionResult is not async so I can't add "await". I just add ".Result" and it calculate result.

```
return Json(_service.AsyncMethod(parameter).Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I post is NOT the answer to question, but I encountered the same issue:

> Cannot access a disposed context instance...

I faced this problem because I was using `MemoryCache` and `DataContext` (Entity Framework Access To Database):

```cs
public IEnumerable<Sentinel00110Log> GetCachedLatestTemperatureAsync()
{
    return _memoryCache.GetOrCreate("latestTemperatures", entry =>
    {
        entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        // It's important to use ToList() here
        // Omitting it will create problems on the enumeration
        return getLatestTemperatures().ToList();
    })!;
}
```

The `getLatestTemperatures()` method returns an `IEnumerable` that accesses the `DataContext`. Storing this in the cache causes it to be enumerated only when it's actually needed (i.e., the next time the cache key is accessed). However, this results in an `Exception` because it attempts to access the `DataContext`, which was created during cache creation and has already been disposed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Create IServiceScopeFactory object and used dependency from IServiceScopeFactory object once it dispose.

```
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory moserviceScopeFactory;
private readonly InvoicesDataContext moInvoicesDataContext;
public ABCController(InvoicesDataContext diInvoicesDataContext, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            moInvoicesDataContext = diInvoicesDataContext;
            moserviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        }
```

My Object has been dispose after execute below code and I want to access object after execute this code. I have created object from IServiceScopeFactory and used. and working fine for me.

```
public async Task<int> generateInvoice()
            {
                List<Guid> loSentId = new List<Guid>();
                Invoices loDataContext = new Invoices(moInvoicesDataContext);
                List<Invoices> loInvoices = loInvoiceDataContext.get("", null, "", null, null, 1, "1", "asc", 1, 5);
    
                bool lblIsSuccess = await loSystemEmails.sendInvoice(loInvoice.stInvoiceNumber, loInvoice.stCompanyEmail, string.Empty, loInvoice.stCompanyName, GetFolderPath.loRootPath + lsSystemFilePath, "1");
                                    if (lblIsSuccess)
                                    {
                                        loSentInvoiceId.Add(loInvoice.unCompanyInvoiceId);
    
                                        

using (var scope = moserviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
                                        {
                                            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<InvoicesDataContext>();

    
                                            int liSuccess = new Invoices(context).SaveData(Convert.ToString(loInvoice.unCompanyInvoiceId), 2, Guid.Empty, "New Zealand Standard Time", "+13:00"); //2 = Sent
                                        }
                                    }
                return loSentInvoiceId != null && loSentInvoiceId.Count > 0 ? loSentInvoiceId.Count : 0;
            }
```

Comment: How does this (poorly-indented) code answer the question? The correct answer has already been given and is *very* simple. Even when creating a scope `async void` will be an issue so this doesn't solve anything.