# .Net core - Stop service / usermanager from being disposed / keep service alive

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, service

I'm developing a .net core web app and I am running into a problem where my Usermanager is being disposed, resulting in an error.

```
public async void DeleteInactiveUserData()
{
    var dayAgo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
    var inactiveGuests = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Guest && u.LastLoginDate < dayAgo);
    var yearAgo = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(-1);
    var inactiveUsers = _userManager.Users.Where(u => !u.Guest && u.LastLoginDate < yearAgo);
    var toBeDeletedUsers = inactiveGuests.Concat(inactiveUsers).ToList();
    for (int i = toBeDeletedUsers.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var user = toBeDeletedUsers[i];
        _logger.LogInformation("Deleting user " + user.UserName + " for inactivity.");
        await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user); // Usermanager is disposed here
    }
}
```

How do I stop service from being disposed of while using the await?

Comment: Please add some details. Post an [mcve] or at least explain why you think it gets disposed. We don't know *anything* about your code. What is `_userManager`? Where is it created? Is your function itself not awaited?

Comment: Also, you say you get an error but you haven't given us the *error message*.

Comment: Thank you for responding. While expanding my question with a reproducible example I ran into the answer. I'm sorry for wasting your time, I will update the question/answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest I did not supply enough details but I ran into the answer while expanding the question. What I learned is this:

Always return async Task instead of async void

[Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543595/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-a-common-cause-of-this-error-is-disposing-a-con)

Await your task before closing the scope:

```
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var accountServive = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAccountService>();
            await accountServive.DeleteInactiveUserData();
        }
```

If you do not await your task the function will continue, the scope will close and your services will be disposed. To learn about async and await go here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/